# How to bring latest Articles in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm new with joomla, just started leaning how to make a templates. I have edited one template i know how to bring all the latest articles on that template by using module type component but i have 6 div tags and i want recent 6 articles to come between div tags. each in one div how to do that?

Comment: What you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dynamic template where you use a [PHP foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) that iterates trough the articles (no matter how many) and places div-tags for each of them.

Like so:

```
<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
    <li>
        <h4><a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo JHTML::_('string.truncate', (strip_tags($item->introtext, '<a><br />')), $item->params->get('readmore_limit')); ?></p>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate little more? Since Im new in Joomla so can you simply guide me about $moduleclass_sfx, 'readmore_limit according to my script

Comment: The variable for the module class is used in all of joomla's standard modules. I also applied it when I made this module. Also the readmore limits are Joomla settings I want the module to use.